# Which unit test set up is correct? Are both tests checking if the function is right and working correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

I just started doing some unit testing for React JS - using Jest / enzyme.
I would like to know which test (format) is more useful and correct to use for future tests. These are 2 different tests that I'm working on it at the moment.

**Unit test 1 : I was writing most of my tests based on this set up**

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import { shallow} from 'enzyme';
import EditWorkflow from './EditWorkflow';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';


//render must import shallow = method to show object structure
//Unit Test  V
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

 describe ('<Workflow />', () => {
    it( 'renders 1 <Workflow /> Component', () => {
        const Component = shallow(<EditWorkflow  name= "workflow"/>);
       expect(Component).toHaveLength(1);

    });
    describe('It renders props correctly', () => {
        const Component = shallow(<EditWorkflow name= "workflow"/>);
        expect(Component.instance().props.name).toBe('workflow');
    })
});
```

**Unit test 2
Different way to write an unit test****

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';
import { Login } from './App';
 import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
let wrapper;

let defaultProps = {
 getSessionContext: jest.fn(),
 checkSession: jest.fn(),
     }

let mockCheckSession;

describe('Login', () => {
 beforeEach(() => {
 mockCheckSession = jest.fn(()=>{return true})
 defaultProps = {
 getSessionContext: jest.fn(),
 checkSession: mockCheckSession,
 }
  })

  it('should render "authorizing..." if theres no session ', () => {
   mockCheckSession = jest.fn(()=>{return false})
   defaultProps.checkSession = mockCheckSession;

  const tree = renderer
  .create(<Login {...defaultProps} />)
  .toJSON();

  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
})
  it('should render null if there is a session ', () => {
  mockCheckSession = jest.fn(()=>{return true})
  defaultProps.checkSession = mockCheckSession;    

  const tree = renderer
  .create(<Login {...defaultProps}/>)
  .toJSON();

 expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
 })
 })
```

Comment: It's hard to get the right answer because the answer is opinionated. I would suggest looking at some of the popular React libraries such as `material-ui` and see if their unit test style matches with your personal or team's preferences.

Comment: @ChristiaanScheermeijer I understand and thanks for answering it.  By just looking at both test above, test 1 seems easier to write and to understand. But I'm not sure if its running correctly or doing what is suppose to do.

Comment: Well, technically it should do a lot more than only checking if the snapshots will match. This will only notify you about potential changes in the rendered component. You essentially want to render your component with a given set of props and expect certain conditions. E.g. expect the `className` to be set on the first element in the rendered output or if a callback prop is being called when clicking a button.

Comment: In another words, if you look on the second test : there are some  given set : defaultProps, right ? technically I will have to do the same thing for the first test

Comment: @ChristiaanScheermeijer I added a different example on CODE 1. Is this what you described on the previous comment

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not providing the full code, it's hard to help you with your current component. Here are some general tips:

One of the goals of writing (good) unit tests for your React components, is to make sure your component behaves and renders as you want it to do. What I usually do, in this part there is no right or wrong, is start reading the render function from top to bottom and take note of each logical part.

## Example #1:

Simply test if the `className` is set on the right element.

```
class Screen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.className}>
        <h1>My screen</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

it('should set the className on the first div', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Screen className="screen" />);

  expect(wrapper.hasClass('screen')).toBeTruthy();
});
```

## Example #2:

If the component renders a part conditionally, you want to test both cases.

```
class Screen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.className}>
        <h1>My screen</h1>
        {this.props.subheading ? <h4>{this.props.subheading}</h4> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

it('should not render the subheading when not given by prop', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Screen />);

  expect(wrapper.find('h4').exists()).toBeFalsy();
});

it('should render the subheading when given by prop', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Screen subheading="My custom subheading!" />);

  expect(wrapper.find('h4').exists()).toBeTruthy();
  expect(wrapper.find('h4').text()).toEqual('My custom subheading!');
});
```

I can give some more examples, but I think you'll get the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christiaan. I was able to figure out and it looks similar to your answer. I was calling the wrong props and had a lot of unnecessary code line on my tests.